# How to reset javascript game when popup window is closed

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

This snake style game is opened in a popup when you click a button on a page, then you are given a start screen and instructions, you click start to begin the game, and when you lose it displays your score and some text, if you close the popup and reopen it, it still shows the score rather than the start screen.

How do I make it reset when the popup is closed?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $("#canvas").addClass("displayNone");
  $("#lose").addClass("displayNone");
  $("#post").removeClass("displayNone");
  $("#controls").removeClass("displayNone");

  $('#play').on('click', function() {
    $('#playdiv').addClass('show-game');
  })

  var canvas = $("#canvas")[0];;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var w = $("#canvas").width();
  var h = $("#canvas").height();
  var cw = 10;
  var d;
  var food;
  var score;
  var snake_array;

  $("#score").addClass("displayNone");
  $("#start").click(function() {
    $("#start").addClass("displayNone");
    $("#lose").addClass("displayNone");
    $("#post").addClass("displayNone");
    $("#canvas").removeClass("displayNone");
    init();
  })
  var keys = [];

  window.addEventListener("keydown",
    function(e) {
      keys[e.keyCode] = true;
      switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 37:
        case 39:
        case 38:
        case 40:
        case 32:
          e.preventDefault();
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    },
    false);

  window.addEventListener('keyup',
    function(e) {
      keys[e.keyCode] = false;
    },
    false);

  // was here

  function init() {
    d = "right";
    create_snake();
    create_food();
    score = 0;

    if (typeof game_loop != "undefined") clearInterval(game_loop);
    game_loop = setInterval(paint, 90);
  }
  //    init();

  function create_snake() {
    var length = 5;
    snake_array = [];
    for (var i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      snake_array.push({
        x: i,
        y: 0
      });
    }
  }

  function create_food() {
    food = {
      x: Math.round(Math.random() * (w - cw) / cw),
      y: Math.round(Math.random() * (h - cw) / cw),
    };
  }

  function paint() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, w, h);

    var nx = snake_array[0].x;
    var ny = snake_array[0].y;

    if (d == "right") nx++;
    else if (d == "left") nx--;
    else if (d == "up") ny--;
    else if (d == "down") ny++;

    if (nx == -1 || nx == w / cw || ny == -1 || ny == h / cw || check_collision(nx, ny, snake_array)) {
      document.querySelector('#score').innerText = 'Your score: ' + score;
      $("#score").removeClass("displayNone");
      $("#lose").removeClass("displayNone");

      $("#start").removeClass("displayNone");
      $("#canvas").addClass("displayNone");
      //init();
      return;
    }

    if (nx == food.x && ny == food.y) {
      var tail = {
        x: nx,
        y: ny
      };
      score++;

      create_food();
    } else {
      var tail = snake_array.pop();
      tail.x = nx;
      tail.y = ny;
    }

    snake_array.unshift(tail);
    for (var i = 0; i < snake_array.length; i++) {
      var c = snake_array[i];
      paint_cell(c.x, c.y);
    }

    paint_cell(food.x, food.y);
    var score_text = "Score: " + score;
    ctx.fillText(score_text, 5, h - 5);
  }

  function paint_cell(x, y) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "pink";
    ctx.fillRect(x * cw, y * cw, cw, cw);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
    ctx.strokeRect(x * cw, y * cw, cw, cw);
  }

  function check_collision(x, y, array) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if (array[i].x == x && array[i].y == y) return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  $(document).keydown(function(e) {
    var key = e.which;
    if (key == "37" && d != "right") d = "left";
    else if (key == "38" && d != "down") d = "up";
    else if (key == "39" && d != "left") d = "right";
    else if (key == "40" && d != "up") d = "down";
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div> unknown HTML please post it here</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried to spot the problem?

Comment: perhaps also post the related html and CSS so we can provide great answers

Comment: `game_loop` is used but is never defined.  Perhaps paste your code here to find some challenges it contains: https://jshint.com/

Comment: is it easier if i just post the url of the page? theres a lot going on and its hard to reproduce in jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you never clean `setInterval` on exit. Please try to `clearInterval`. Attach to the `window`, not local valriable.

```
const window.timerId = setInterval(init, 9000)
```

// On init

```
if (window.game_loop != "undefined") clearInterval(game_loop);
    window.game_loop = setInterval(paint, 90);
```

Comment: is this in place of the setInterval currently in the code?

`if (typeof game_loop != "undefined") clearInterval(game_loop);
        game_loop = setInterval(paint, 90);
`

Comment: seems, game_loop doesn not attached to window, Try explicit assign

Comment: hmm doesnt seem to be working, could you place your code into my code please?